# Browser Plugin for Safari and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, safari, browser-plugin

Can we use webkit framework developing browser plugin for both IE (On Windows) and Safari (on Mac)?
I am asking on the basis of http://docs.huihoo.com/webkit/WebKit_PluginProgTopic.pdf

Could any one who has experimented with webkit reply ?

Thanks and Regards
Vijayanand

Answer (score 0):

No, WebKit & NPAPI plugins can't be directly used for IE.

You could however write a wrapper plugin for IE that hosts an NPAPI plugin in IE. Alternatively the [FireBreath project](http://code.google.com/p/firebreath/) already solves your problem: it allows you to write cross-platform/cross-browser plugins from one code base.